# SVN (windows) add file of specific type with sub-directories

Tags: svn

I have a large directory (4gb +) that I am planning to add to SVN but I have a need to quickly add just the .php files in all directories. How can I go about this?

The following only added the files at the . current directory level:

```
svn add *.php
```

I've tried using --recursive but it says add does not accept the option.